# kind of singularity of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is holomorphic on $0<|z|<2$ and satisfies $ f(\frac{1}{n}) = n^2 $ and $ f(-\frac{1}{n}) = n^3 $ what kind of singularity does f have at 0?

Well at least  is not removable since it's not bounded. But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: If $f$ had a pole of order $k$, it would have asymptotics like $f(z)\sim \mathrm{const}\cdot z^{-k}$ as $z$ approaches zero in *any* way.